# Read files from a dir in python and sort them

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to read all the files that exist in the path using python. My files are jpg files correspond to videos and the filename:

```
img_1089_IEO_HAP_MD_5_.jpg
img_1089_IEO_HAP_MD_1_.jpg
...
img_1068_IWL_SAD_XX_4_.jpg
```

All the terms except the last one are indicating a specific video (img_1089_IEO_HAP_MD_...jpg). When i just use `os.listdir(path)` the order of files is kind of random. I want to read all the jpg files with sorted order in order to be able to store them in a dictionary that will contain each video name and all the correspondent frames. Any help of how can I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort the directory lexicographically by simply wrapping the `os.listdir` call in `sorted`:

```
for file in sorted(os.listdir(directory)):
    print(file)
```

However, if your ultimate goal is to use the filenames as keys in a dictionary, order won't matter since dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: I know the file names of the videos, so for each filename i want to store together all the frames in a dictionary.